# Problems with multiple and dynamic html popover on showing and hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, popover, bootstrap-popover

before all thanks for reading.

So... I have a problem with bootstrap popover. I have tried many configurations with no success, so I'll try to explain the problem as clearer as I can.

I have multiple elements within bootstrap columns and when the user click on one of them a popover comes out with a form in its popover-content.

Every form is different due to its attributes, you can choose different options in the popover and then send the form.

Untill this point everything is fine, the popover works correctly. The thing is that when I click a second time over the same element in order to hide the popover, popover hides but not the title and the next popover I click content is empty, I mean, popover content stop working, it only show titles.

I think I'm missing something but I can't find out what.

The code that load the content:

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
  trigger: "click focus",
  template:'<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-header"></h3><a href="#" class="popover-close">&otimes;</a><div class="popover-body"></div></div>',
  content: function() {
    var $html = $(this).parent().find(".prod-popover").eq(0).html();
    return $(".popover-content").html($html);
  }
});
```

I've tried with trigger focus, click, manual and a mix of them with the same results.
I have also tried changing the wrapper .popover-content with #popover-content.

Code to hide popover:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.popover-close", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(".popover-content").popover('hide');
  return false;
});
```

Another for hiding found here in stack overflow

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if ($(".popover").has(e.target).length == 0 || $(e.target).is(".close")) {
    $("#popoverId").popover("hide");
  }
});
```

Another one:

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").on('click', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();
        $("[data-toggle=popover]").not(this).popover('hide');
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bt-border k-item" data-placement="right" data-toggle="popover" data-title="Whatever" data-container="body" data-html="true">
<div class="hidden prod-popover">
    <form class="cart" role="form" method="post" action="">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Label</label>
            <textarea rows="2" placeholder="PLACEHOLDER"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="btn-group pop-quantity" role="group">
                <input type="text" value="1" min="1" step="1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button">Send<button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"><img src="SRC" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <h4 class="no-pad-bt">Whatever</h4>
        <p class="no-pad-bt">Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 text-right">
        <p>Price</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Inside trigger value, you have put `"click | focus"`, but in docs:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers-options, it says: "You may pass multiple triggers; separate them with a space.", so probably you need `"click focus"` without pipe.

Comment: Yes, another try...I've tried separate and one by one as well.

Comment: Sorry pointing docs again. Inside template value, you have 'popover-body' and 'popover-header' instead of 'popover-content' and 'popover-title'. Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: No sorries, your point of view and docs are wellcome. I've tried with popover-content and popover-title, as you pointed, and it is doing weird things, sometimes it is shown and sometimes it is not. Anyway I've tried with and without template as well, I got template from here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/. Thank you very much for your time.